# Drag & Drop in Ionic/Angular app: `e.gesture` undefined, and using two different Controllers for Drag and Drop

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, ionic-framework

I'm building an app that needs to feature Drag & Drop as an interaction mode. Specifically, imagine an Ionic `Side Menu`, containing an `<ion-list>` of people. Any one of these people in the list should be able to be dragged and dropped into a container, somewhere in the view (but not dropped back into the `<ion-list>`). Now, a problem and a question:

*Problem*: I implemented an Angular Drag & Drop library (http://www.directiv.es/Angular-DragDrop). It seems to work - inasmuch as a ghost image is draggable. But, a **`TypeError: e.gesture is undefined`** is thrown, in `ionic.bundle`, line 6917. Why is this error being thrown, as soon as I click a person in the list and start dragging? More importantly, how to correct this? Since it's not thrown in the Drag & Drop library, it suggests an issue within Ionic, no?

*Question*: This may be more of an Angular than Ionic question, but here goes: The `<ion-list>` containing the people list is under the control of one `Controller` (say, `ControllerA`), while the container into which a person from this list is to be dropped is under the control of another `Controller` (say, `ControllerB`). Now, is it actually possible to have the Drag part of Drag & Drop reside in one `Controller`, and the Drop part of Drag & Drop reside in another? It's not working for me, and I don't know if it's because of the undefined gesture or - even if gesture were defined and not in error - it's because the same `Controller` is not handling both Drag and Drop. (Both the container and the list have the required `Directive`s present in the templates, and functions to handle the Drop are defined.) If the Drag & Drop can be split across two different Controllers, then presumably you'd need to either use `$broadcast/$on` or a shared `Service` to handle the interaction between them, right? Can anyone clarify this?

Anyway, first things first: How to solve the **`TypeError: e.gesture is undefined`** error being thrown at the start of a Drag operation. All help much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Does this library work well for you on mobile? It does not to me...

Comment: https://github.com/kunder-lab/ionic-list-draggable-item

Answer (score 1):

I did a brilliant job using this ngDraggable AngularJS Directive: https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this!

Comment: I've been trying to get the examples on ngDraggable to work in ionic without success. And yes I did add the `data-tap-disabled="true"` on the parent element. Still doesn't work. Could you possibly provide a working Codepen / Plunker for us?

Comment: Im working with hammerjs, you really should check, there is also other lib called angular.hammer that plugs hammerjs to your angularjs app

Comment: I can't get ngDraggalble to work inside ionic either, works in the browser but not in IonicView or mobile.

Comment: also can't get ngDraggable to perform natively on mobile, though it does work great on web.